# Doctrine2 & Symfony2: Reset ID value on save when in foreach loop

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

See the following code:

```
$passwords = array('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccccc', 'dddd', 'eeeee');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setName('Joe Bloggs');
$foo->setTitle('Mr');
foreach ($passwords as $password) {
    $foo->setPassword($password);
    $em->persist($foo);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Here when I try to save the `$foo` object, i'd hope to save it X number of times, where X is the length of `$passwords`, however it just inserts the value once, then updates it the other 4 times.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this so that it inserts the record 5 times.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice between **creation** and **update** is made on the object identification :

- new object => creation
- existing object => update

So, don't try to optimize treatment by not repeating setName and setTitle, but you can execute flush() only once ;) :

```
$passwords = array('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccccc', 'dddd', 'eeeee');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
foreach ($passwords as $password) {
    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->setName('Joe Bloggs');
    $foo->setTitle('Mr');
    $foo->setPassword($password);
    $em->persist($foo);
}
$em->flush();
```